# No primary or candidate keys in the referenced table that match the referencing column list in the foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is Code for the Table:-

```sql
create table eqpDetail
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    depttCode varchar(20),
    subDepttCode varchar(20),
    lineCode varchar(10) foreign key references line(lineCode) NOT NULL,
    sysCode varchar(20) foreign key references system(sysCode) NOT NULL,
    subSysCode varchar(20) foreign key references subSystem(subSyscode) NOT NULL,
    stnCode varchar(25) foreign key references station(stnCode) NOT NULL,   
    eqpId varchar(20) not null,
    eqpType varchar(20),
    eqpDir varchar(10),
    eqpLoc varchar(50),
    eqpArea varchar(50),
    eqpSr varchar(20),
    eqpMake varchar(20),
    eqpVersion varchar(20),
    eqpManuf varchar(50) foreign key references company(compCode),
    eqpcountryCode varchar(10) foreign key references country(countryCode),
    eqpVendor varchar(50) foreign key references company(compCode),
    isActive bit not null,
    isEnabled bit not null,
    tabObjects int foreign key references listTable(tableId),
    tabFaults int foreign key references listTable(tableId),
    tabAct int foreign key references listTable(tableId),
    tabDamage int foreign key references listTable(tableId),
    tabCause int foreign key references listTable(tableId),
    tabTask int foreign key references listTable(tableId),
    tabCatPro int foreign key references listTable(tableId),
    tableId int foreign key references listTable(tableId),
    tableTypeId intforeign key references listTable(tableId),

    primary key(lineCode, stnCode, sysCode, subSysCode, eqpId),

    CONSTRAINT PFK2 
        FOREIGN KEY (tableId, depttCode, subDepttCode, sysCode, subSysCode, tableTypeId) 
        REFERENCES listTable (tableId, depttCode, subDepttCode, sysCode, subSysCode, tableTypeId),

)
```

Error :

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'listTable' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key----

other tables:

```sql
create table listTable
(
    tableId int identity(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    depttCode varchar(20) foreign key references deptt(depttCode) not null,
    subDepttCode varchar(20) foreign key references subDeptt(subDepttCode) not null,
    sysCode varchar(20) foreign key references system(sysCode) not null,
    subSysCode varchar(20) foreign key references subSystem(subSysCode) not null,      
    lineCode varchar(10) foreign key references line(lineCode) not null,    
    tableTypeId int foreign key references tableType(tableTypeId) not null,                                        
    tableName varchar(20) not null unique,                                 
    SAP_CodeGroup varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    SAP_Code varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    isActive bit NOT NULL,
    primary key(tableId, depttCode, subDepttCode, sysCode, subSysCode, tableTypeId),
)

create table company
(
    id int identity(1,1),
    compCode varchar(50) primary key,
    compCountry varchar(10) foreign key references country(countryCode),
)
```

EqpDetail is the main table used to store data.
this table references listTable, which stores the table names.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. The *only* PK/Unique Index (according to the above) on the table `listTable` is on the columns `depttCode, subDepttCode, sysCode, subSysCode, tableTypeId`; as in all of those columns combined make your Primary Index. Your Foreign Keys are trying to use `tableId` as a Foreign Key, but that column isn't unique nor a primary key.

Comment: Bad idea - please read [one table to rule them all](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/58372/is-the-one-description-table-to-rule-them-all-approach-good)

Answer (score 0):

The id columns (id, tableId...) should be set as PRIMARY KEY

or at least to be set as unique index,

In order to "promise" no duplication for the identity.

For example:

```
create table listTable
(
    tableId int identity(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    ...
```

The identity(1,1) only creates a running number to be inserted automatically, but does not promise uniqueness.

Comment: i revised, tableId is also primary key, but problem persists.

Comment: if you made any changes, please edit your example. I don't see primary key or unique index applied on tableId column in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this line:

```
    CONSTRAINT PFK2 
        FOREIGN KEY (tableId, depttCode, subDepttCode, sysCode, subSysCode, tableTypeId) 
        REFERENCES listTable (tableId, depttCode, subDepttCode, sysCode, subSysCode, tableTypeId)
```

you already referenced the foreign keys in the columns definitions.

or remove the other references, if this composite foreign key is what you really want.

```
tabObjects int foreign key references listTable(tableId),
tabFaults int foreign key references listTable(tableId),
tabAct int foreign key references listTable(tableId),
tabDamage int foreign key references listTable(tableId),
tabCause int foreign key references listTable(tableId),
tabTask int foreign key references listTable(tableId),
tabCatPro int foreign key references listTable(tableId),
tableId int foreign key references listTable(tableId),
tableTypeId intforeign key references listTable(tableId),
```

if tableId is unique / primary key - there's no reason to have a composite primary key and composite foreign key